# Go 1.16 embed: Как обратится к папке которая находится выше .go файла?

Tags: golang

У меня есть следующая структура папок в программе:

```
├───global
└───resource
   │   questions.json
   ├───db
   └───manager
           manager.go
```

Мне нужно просканировать содержимое папки resource из файла manager.go.
То есть подняться на 3 уровня выше и зайти в папку ***.../resource***

```
// Данная конструкция не работает.
package manager

import "embed"

//go:embed .../resource
var resource embed.FS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и задумывалось:

> The patterns are interpreted **relative** to the package directory containing the source file. The path separator is a forward slash, even on Windows systems. Patterns **may not** contain ‘.’ or ‘..’ or empty path elements, nor may they begin or end with a slash

Я бы вынес все переменные, которые нужно "эмбеддить" в пакет `resource` и затем использовал их как обычные переменные `go`.

Раз вы пишете `resource` с маленькой буквы, значит, код, в котором вы собираетесь использовать эту переменую, расположен где-то рядом. В том же файле или пакете. Вот этого я бы точно делать не стал, смешивать данные и код. Код отдельно, данные отдельно.